# Como habilitar cookies no Electron

Tags: javascript, cookies, electron

Estou precisando utilizar cookies http only no electron, mas os mesmos estão desabilitados alguém sabe como habilitar?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O ambiente *renderer* do Electron não possui, até o momento, suporte para a API `document.cookie`. Assim, bibliotecas como o Google Analytics ou similares que utilizam cookies do lado do cliente não irão funcionar porque não podem definir cookies.

Para contornar este problema você pode utilizar o [pacote `electron-cookies`](https://github.com/hstove/electron-cookies).

**Instalação**

> `npm install electron-cookies`

**Uso**

No código *renderer* da sua solução, basta especificar o pacote:

> `require('electron-cookies')`

Seus cookies serão então armazenados no `localStorage`.

Fonte: https://github.com/hstove/electron-cookies

Comment: já tinha utilizado ele, e fiz o teste novamente e não deu certo, talvez seja pq os cookies q preciso são http only e o javascript não tem acesso.

Comment: @RodrigoMartins Entendo. Acredito que não exista, no momento, suporte  necessário a cookies com filtro de protocolo. =/